# How to make server sided controls based div/menu separate and resuable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages

I have a sidebar in asp.net, it has server side controls like combobox and checkbox list, but i want to use the same control on multiple pages, is there some way to tackle it?
i used acx control but they dont provide server side property, is there some modern way of .net to handle this.
See img.
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "ascx controls don't provide server side property" ?

Comment: It looks like ASCX user controls are the tool for this task. But you might also consider master pages, possibly nested master pages.